# Fuse 7.2 on EAP 7.2 won't install

Tags: jboss7.x, jbossfuse

I have downloaded and installed EAP 7.2.0 and I applied the patch 7.2.4. Now I want to install Fuse 7.2 for EAP on it. The Getting started document says:

> Navigate to the directory where you want to install (EAP_HOME) and run the  installer, including the downloaded file location and name in the command. For example:
>
> java -jar TEMP_LOCATION/fuse-eap-installer-7.2.fuse-000085-redhat-1.jar

The file I have downloaded has a different name, so I do:

```
java -jar ../Téléchargements/fuse-eap-installer-7.2.0.fuse-720018-redhat-00002.jar
```

And I get the following exception:

```
Copy to repository: fuse-patch-distro-wildfly-3.1.0.fuse-720026-redhat-00001.zip
Copy to repository: fuse-eap-distro-7.2.0.fuse-720018-redhat-00002.zip
Run command: java -Djboss.home=. -Dlogging.configuration=file:bin/fusepatch-logging.properties -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules org.wildfly.extras.patch --add file:fusepatch/repository/fuse-patch-distro-wildfly-3.1.0.fuse-720026-redhat-00001.zip
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: java.se
  at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266)
  at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
  at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650)
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:296)
  at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:437)
Error: Command did not terminate normally
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm using Java 13. On Windows 10, with Java 13 as well, seems to work. At least I was able to install but I'm not sure
whether I followed exactly the same steps. Could anyone please help me with this as otherwise I need to work on Windows and I hate that ?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 5):

Red Hat Fuse 7.2 on EAP is supported only on EAP 7.1 and Java 1.8. You can find the supported configurations for each release here:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/310603

Comment: Okay, thanks, for the update. On the RedHat Customer Portal I've seen that the last release of Fuse is 7.5. Do you know on what release of EAP and Karaf this might be installed ?

Comment: Fuse 7.5 will support EAP 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I installed Fuse 7.4 on EAP 7.2.1 and it works with Java 12.